# Google Apps Script : Save a copy of shared folders

Tags: google-apps-script

In Google Docs 'Add to Drive' does not save the folders to one's drive, it merely adds a link to the user's drive. Whenever a change is made on one side, it is readily reflected on the other. It includes deletion and update of files.

I want to save  copies of the folders to "My Drive" (better if it can be done for particular set of users), so that it is isolated from the copy of the person who shared it. The following function, lists all the folders `sharedWithMe`.

```
function SearchAndSave() {
  var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders('sharedWithMe');
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
   var folder = folders.next();
   Logger.log(folder.getName()); 

 }
}
```

I thought of `makeCopy()`.`makeCopy()` works for files. Does it work for folders too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got the script working.It is somewhat crude though. Just blindly clones all the folders shared with me.

```
function start() {

   var folders = DriveApp.searchFolders('sharedWithMe');
   while (folders.hasNext()) {
   var sourceFolder = folders.next();
   var targetFolder = 'Copy of ' + sourceFolder;
   Logger.log(sourceFolder);
   Logger.log(targetFolder);

  var source = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sourceFolder);
  var target = DriveApp.createFolder(targetFolder);

  if (source.hasNext()) {
    copyFolder(source.next(), target);
  }

 }
}

function copyFolder(source, target) {

  var folders = source.getFolders();
  var files   = source.getFiles();

  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
  }

  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var targetFolder = target.createFolder(folderName);
    copyFolder(subFolder, targetFolder);
  }  

}
```

Only one problem, in case of large number of shared folders the script terminates with `Execution failed: Exceeded maximum execution time [362.575 seconds total runtime]`. Please suggest if you have any idea.

Comment: Some changes I did: https://gist.github.com/qgustavor/6a1b6ab701f73a4cdec2e2b491babb33

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Gustavo Rodrigues's post, He made a great modification but I will say I noticed that it cause alot more failures than I had previously gotten with other scripts.  After I compared it, I noticed he throws file.getName() into var fileName.  And then calls the variable into action at:

```
    file.makeCopy(fileName, target);
```

This will work for most of the stuff on my drive but for some reason it was causing alot of errors.  To get around this I needed to replace it with:

```
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), target);
```

I honstely am not sure why or how...but if you have an answer I'm all ears.  Just know that replacing the variable seemed to work much better and is still working well for me, as we speak.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a great script that works still in 2021 with Jersun Amos change.
Just clarifying as I was struggeling with the gist script.
getFolderById () takes the last part of the address.

Great timesaver.
Thanks